# Value cannot be null - How to get all entries of a database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco7

Im just trying to output all entries from a database table in Visual Studio and get the following error:

**Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.**

Im sure that the name of the database is correct and there are also entries, because the Insert-Method works fine.

Perhaps there is a parsing problem or must I change something in my web.config?

Here is my Code. Hope somebody can help me:

**My Model:**

```
[TableName("kb_Chat_Message")]
[PrimaryKey("id", autoIncrement = true)]
public class ChatMessage
{

    public static string TABLE_NAME = "kb_Chat_Message";
    public static string ROW_ID = "id";
    public static string MESSAGE = "message";
    public static string GROUP = "group";
    public static string ROW_TIME = "timestamp";

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } 

    public ChatMessage(string message, string groupName, DateTime time) {

        this.message = message;
        this.group = groupName;
        this.timestamp = time;

    }
}
```

**My Repository:**

```
 public class ChatRepository
{
    private readonly UmbracoDatabase _database;

    public ChatRepository()
    {
        _database = ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;
    }

    public IList<ChatMessage> GetAll()
    {
        // === Next line throws System.ArgumentNullException ===
        return _database.Fetch<ChatMessage>("SELECT * FROM " + ChatMessage.TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public void Insert(ChatMessage message)
    {
        _database.Insert(message);
    }

}
```

**My Hub:**

```
var chatrepo = new ChatRepository();

foreach (var msg in chatrepo.GetAll())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg.message);   
}
```

**My Database looks like:**
[Database named "kb_Chat_Message"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lIIi.png)

Comment: Which code line throws an `System.ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: This one in my Repo: return _database.Fetch<ChatMessage>("SELECT * FROM " + ChatMessage.TABLE_NAME);

Comment: could it be that the table kb_Chat_Message is not in your master database, or try to use dbo.kb_Chat_Message ?

Comment: I m using Umbraco and this table is a part of my master database. I've already tried to rename it in dbo.kb_Chat_Message, but nothing changed.

Comment: First thing to check is whether `_database != null`. If it is, you know that there is a problem with fetching the message.

Comment: return _database.Fetch<ChatMessage>(new Sql().Select("*").From(ChatMessage.TABLE_NAME));

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : _database can't be null when my insert method works fine, or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @benni_mac_b : same exception

Comment: @TomD: When you get an exception, you generally debug the code by setting a break point on the code line generating the exception. This allows you to inspect the values involved. This is better than making any assumptions. Since the general assumption was that the code should work fine, there must be something wrong with some assumption.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : When I set a breakpoint, the following is displayed:

        _database = {Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase}

         base = {Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase}

          CommandTimeout = 0
          Connection = null
          CurrentTransactionIsolationLevel = Unspecified
          EnableAutoSelect = true
          EnableNamedParams = true
          ForceDateTimesToUtc = true
          KeepConnectionAlive = false
          LastArgs = null
          LastCommand = ""
          LastSQL = null
          OneTimeCommandTimeout = 0

Comment: This confirms your assumption that `_database` is not null and that indeed the `ArgumentNullException` must be thrown by the call of `Fetch`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I m totally agree with you. So do you have any idea why my Fetch don't work?

Comment: Are you trying to read a NULL value from the DB into `id` or `timestamp`? These fields are not nullable in your class `ChatMessage`. benni_mac_b shows how you can make `timestamp` nullable.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I think I have solved the problem. When I add an new constructor without parameters to my model, everything works fine. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. The `Fetch` statement does not know how to use these parameters when creating a new `ChatMessage`. I just wonder why there is no generic type constraint `new()` on the generic type parameter of `Fetch<T>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Then perhaps you should try something like this

```
public IList<ChatMessage> GetAll()
    {
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Yourconnection"].ToString();

        ChatMessage _chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        IList<ChatMessage> _all_chatMessages = new List<ChatMessage>();
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            string oString = "Select * from kb_Chat_Message";
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);         
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {    
                 _chatMessages.RequiredField = oReader["RequiredFieldname"].ToString();                     
         _all_chatMessages.Add(_chatMessage)
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }               
          }
        return _all_chatMessages;
       }
```

let me know...

Comment: When I put a break point at this line the value in it is null: **databaseResult = null**

The name of the table in my database is dbo.kb_Chat_Message.

Comment: ...if that's correct then ...no value is being retrieved from the database.
try this...remove ...+ ChatMessage.TABLE_NAME...and do this instead
"SELECT * FROM kb_Chat_Message" and lets see.

Comment: I had already tried this, same exception. Parsing issue?

Because wenn I try a table name which does not exist I get the following error: **Invalid object name 'kb_Chat_Meswsage'.**

Comment: @TomD i have changed the code perhaps try that one and see...its not as clean but we can confirm the dbconnection and retrieve data with that...while you still look for a cleaner answer

Comment: Now I have an ouput from my database table. So might it be possible that he has no access to the right connectionString? If it is, why does the insert methode works fine?

Comment: I doubt its the connectionString issue because if it works for Insert, then it would work for Select. It might be a problem with your repository or another class leading to the way data is selected from the database so you will have to go deeper to each sub class. recheck any repository or generic class.

Comment: When I add an new constructor without parameters to my model, everything works fine. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, if you had already defined a constructor with parameters. Good thinking. Glad it all worked out.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your efforts!